# converting the duration column into short, medium, long values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binning

how to Convert the duration column into short, medium, long values. Come up with the boundaries by splitting the duration range in 3 equal size ranges

```py
df['duration'].head()
```

Output:

```py
0      01:13
1      01:09
2      01:40
3      00:48
4      00:49
       ...  
98     00:52
99     01:10
100    01:05
101    01:09
102    00:58
Name: duration, Length: 103, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) on the Series of Timedelta after conversion with [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['bin'] = pd.cut(pd.to_timedelta(df['duration']+':00'),
                   bins=3, labels=['low', 'medium', 'high'])
```

*NB. assuming a `HH:MM` format here, for `MM:SS`, use `'00:'+df['duration']`*

output:

```
    duration     bin
0      01:13  medium
1      01:09  medium
2      01:40    high
3      00:48     low
4      00:49     low
...      ...     ...
98     00:52     low
99     01:10  medium
100    01:05     low
101    01:09  medium
102    00:58     low
```

If you also want the boundaries:

```
df['bin'], boundaries = pd.cut(pd.to_timedelta(df['duration']+':00'),
                               bins=3, labels=['low', 'medium', 'high'],
                               retbins=True
                              )

print(boundaries)
```

output:

```
TimedeltaIndex(['0 days 00:47:56.880000',        '0 days 01:05:20',
                       '0 days 01:22:40',        '0 days 01:40:00'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```